# Iterate through workbooks to produce new workbook with a new filename

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I want to iterate through workbooks in my directory. For each workbook, I want a new workbook produced.

I want the new workbooks to be named after the files it is iterating through, but with 'New' in front of it (ideally the new workbooks should be brand new and not a duplicate of the previous workbooks, is this even possible?)

The code below seems to be doing something, but isn't quite right

```
import win32com.client as win32
bk_2_to_5 = [filename2, filename3, filename4, filename5]

for x in bk_2_to_5:
       excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
       excel.Visible = True         
       wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
       wb.SaveAs('New' + x + sh'*.xlsx')
       excel.Application.Quit()
```

I want new books to be produced called Newfilename2.xlsx, Newfilename3.xlsx, and such forth

Anybody know a solution?

EDIT:

The output is this. Note that a blank workbook opens up, but it does not autosave. If I do  wb.SaveAs('New.xlsx'), it saves as New.xlsx, but that is not what I am after, I want it named after each file with 'New' as a prefix.

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Office Excel', 'SaveAs method of Workbook class failed', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: How do you mean "the code below seems to be doing something" ? Can you put here its output too?

Comment: Hi kingJulian, the excel application opens up and a blank workbook is produced. But it doesn't save. I have to save it manually which is not what I want. I'll add the output in the main question

Comment: Where is `sh` defined? Also, you can try to circumvent this problem by storing `'New' + x + sh'*.xlsx'` into a variable and then pass this variable, say `new_filename`, to the function like this `wb.SaveAs(new_filename)`.

Comment: But how would I make it so that it would save as the name of the file it is iterating through each time? By specifying or hardcoding the new file name as in `wb.SaveAs(new_filename)` , it would just keep asking me if it should overwrite that file. I need it to save as a new name for every iteration. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I 'm missing your point but I don't think you are hardcoding it. By doing `new_filename = 'New' + x + sh'*.xlsx'`, every-time you iterate over your list, x will be substituted with `filename2`, `filename3` etc thus `new_filename` will contain a new name for every iteration. Also, what is the `sh`?

Comment: Oh, `sh` is a loop variable in the script. I probably should have mentioned that this is a snippet of a nested loop. `sh` should give the number of the file (2, 2a, 2b, 3 etc) and then x should produce the filename. But actually I'm willing to get rid of that if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the **[xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt)** module. The below example might help.

**Ex:**

```
import xlwt

bk_2_to_5 = ["filename2", "filename3", "filename4", "filename5"]

for  b in bk_2_to_5:
    book = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = book.add_sheet("data", cell_overwrite_ok=True)             
    book.save('New' + b  + '.xls')
```

Comment: After trying this, new files are produced, but when I open the excel files, they are all corrupted!

Comment: Get this output error: `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`. The files are produced but I get "Newfilename2.xlsx.xls" and so on... Would it be possible to maybe just have Newfilename2.xls?

Comment: Updated solution above